# Android Studio AVD drag/drop app, "app isn't installed" ...log uncomprehensive

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

- Ionic Gradle app in Android Studio
- Using SDK 30, Tools 30.0.2
- Can build .APK release (including signing), no errors

Problem: "App not installed" in emulator, do not see any errors!? How to debug

Log: https://dojo.telerik.com/EkejObUC (could not fit on StOverf.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: go to setttings > apps > delete your app if you see it in list.

Comment: I did, reinstalled it. The problem (my title is confusing) is that the app sais "not installed" and my log does help